# NoSuchMethodError (NoSuchMethodError: The method '[]' was called on null. Receiver: null Tried calling: [](0))

Tags: flutter, api, dart, visual-studio-code

I am trying to create an application and this application gets information from the open-meteo API. I keep on encountering some errors that don't know how to fix. Would appreciate any help!!

title: Text(snapshot.data[i].longitude), //This is the line that is producing the error

```
import 'dart:convert'; 
import 'dart:ffi';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart'; 
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

void main() => runApp(MaterialApp( 
home: HomePage(), 
debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false, 
));

class HomePage extends StatefulWidget { 
@override 
_HomePageState createState() => _HomePageState(); 
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> { 
Future getUserData() async { 

var response = await http.get(Uri.parse( 'https://api.open-meteo.com/v1/forecast?latitude=52.52&longitude=13.41&hourly=temperature_2m')); 
var jsonData = jsonDecode(response.body); 
List<User> users = [];

for (var u in (jsonData)) {
  User user = User(u['longitude'], u['latitude'], u['hourly'], u['time'],u['temperature']);
  users.add(user);
}

print(users.length);
return users;
}



@override 

Widget build(BuildContext context) { 
 return Scaffold( 
  appBar: AppBar( 
   title: Text('Rangers Tool'), 
), 
 body: Container( 
 child: Card( 
   child: FutureBuilder( 
 future: getUserData(), 
 builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) { 
return ListView.builder(
              itemCount: snapshot.data?.length,
              itemBuilder: (context, i) {

 return ListTile( 
  title: Text(snapshot.data[i].longitude), 
  subtitle: Text(snapshot.data[i].latitude), 
); 
}); 
} 

}, 

))), ); } }

class User { 

final String longitude, latitude, hourly, time, temperature;

User(this.longitude, this.latitude, this.hourly, this.time, this.temperature); }
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add a condition to make sure that data is there by checking the status of the `snapshot` before using it to build your list.  Similar to this:

```
FutureBuilder(
    future: _fetchListItems(),
    builder:(context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
        if (!snapshot.hasData) {
            return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
         } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
              SnapshotError(snapshot.error),
         } else {
            return ListView.builder(
              itemCount: snapshot.data?.length,
              itemBuilder: (context, i) {

           return ListTile( 
           title: Text(snapshot.data[i].longitude), 
           subtitle: Text(snapshot.data[i].latitude), 
           );                                          
         }
     }
)
```

Comment: Thank you for the help!! I did do this and I am still getting the error:NoSuchMethodError (NoSuchMethodError: The method '[]' was called on null.
Receiver: null
Tried calling: [](0))

Comment: I've updated my answer as I see now what is wrong  - try the above.

Comment: Thank you so much it solved that error for me!!

Comment: Glad it worked for you! Typically when you mark an answer as accepted, you also upvote the answer as well.  In turn, it is common courtesy to upvote the question when you answer one as well.  Or if you find a solution that helps you, upvote that answer and the questions because the original poster of the question got helped get you to that solution.

Comment: Im sorry I wasn't aware of this, thank you for letting me know! Thank you again for the help!!

Comment: I added an else-if block to handle if there is an error in your future.  Not often do they hit but if you don't have it, it would be ignored without it.